# Jquery Assign label text which is in gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

How to get the label which is inside gridview and assign a text for that label using jquery. In general we use the following for assigning a text in jquery

`("[id$='label1']").val('Value')` or `$('#<%=label1.ClientID%>').val('Value')`

But as the control is inside the gridview how can I assign the text

This is my ListView

```
 <tr>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" rowspan="2">
<asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
 <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center;" rowspan="2">
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstname1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
```

and in my script file I write as per below

`$("[id$='lblID']").text('Value');` Which didn't worked

Comment: Your second option will do.

Answer (score 0):

use `text()` or `html()`... `val()` is for `input` 
try this

```
$("[id$='label1']").text('Value')
```

**updated**

```
$('#<%= lblID.ClientID %>').html('Value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<%="#"+GridViewData.ClientID %>').find('span[id*="Label1"]').text("yourdata");
```

& as @bipen said you can use any three of functions `text(), html(), or val()`.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to open the html view-source and find its generated ID attribute value. It may be something like

```
<span id="MainContent_GridView1_Label1">abc</span>
```

and then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id$='MainContent_GridView1_Lable1']").text('Hello Folk');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the row index for that.

The gridview control creates the labels name like: GridViewName_LabelName_RowIndex

You have to use the class if you want to set the same value to all the labels:

```
$(".ClassName").text('Value');
```

Or give the row number to selector:

```
$("[id$='YOURGRIDVIEWNAME_lblID_ROWINDEX']").text('Value');
```